# Relay query that that depends on data from a Relay query

Tags: relayjs

I'm trying to perform a Relay query that that depends on data from another relay query

Assuming this runs under a url like `/job/{jobID}`

React

```js
render() {

  const job = this.props.job

  return(
      <h1>{job.name}</h1>

      <TasksOutstanding 
        project={job.project} 
        from={job.startDate} 
        to={job.finishDate} />
  ) 
}
```

Relay

```js
  fragments: {
    job: () => Relay.QL`
      fragment on Job {
        name
        startDate
        finishDate
        project {
          ${TasksOutstanding.getFragment('project')}
        }
     }
    `,
```

So I need to get startDate and finishDate into the fragment, something like `${TasksOutstanding.getFragment('project',{from, to})}`

But these values (`from` `to`) are unknown on the initial fetch ( all I have then is the jobID)

How are people dealing with this? Should I just execute a second request on component did mount once I have the startDate and finishDate values ?

Answer (score 1):

You need to create field with [arguments](http://graphql.org/learn/schema/#arguments), this is GraqhQL feature and you should be able to do it with your tool for modeling the schema.

Relay's [variables](https://facebook.github.io/relay/docs/api-reference-relay-container.html#variables) also will be useful. They will solve the problem that you don't know them on initial fetch.

So declare `project` field with `from` and `to` arguments, query the field using arguments are return appropriate data for project field. Your container should look like this:

```
initialVariables: {
   from: null,
   to: null
},

fragments: {
   job: () => Relay.QL`
     fragment on Job {
       name
       startDate
       finishDate
       project(from: $from, to: $to) {
         ${TasksOutstanding.getFragment('project')}
       }
     }
   `,
}
```

Then during the application life, you can set your variables using [setVariables](https://facebook.github.io/relay/docs/api-reference-relay-container.html#variables) to `job.startDate` and `job.finishDate`  and have proper `project` fetched.

Comment: Ok thanks, so the way to solve this is to perform a subsequent request with setVariables.  This makes sense, I was just hoping that there would be some way to do this in a single request.